# App crash after interegrating firebase authentication in my app

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin

My app crashes on starting it (basically any activity with firebase code) after adding firebase authentication

This is the logcat

```
2022-07-14 20:17:21.538 15482-15482/com.example.flimer E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.flimer, PID: 15482
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.flimer/com.example.flimer.SignUp}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3086)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3318)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:113)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:71)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:226)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7212)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:576)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:956)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.pm.ApplicationInfo android.content.Context.getApplicationInfo()' on a null object reference
        at android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationInfo(ContextWrapper.java:170)
        at android.view.ContextThemeWrapper.getTheme(ContextThemeWrapper.java:157)
        at android.content.Context.obtainStyledAttributes(Context.java:682)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:848)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.ensureSubDecor(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:815)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.findViewById(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:640)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.findViewById(AppCompatActivity.java:259)
        at com.example.flimer.SignUp.<init>(SignUp.kt:15)
        at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
        at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:69)
        at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3074)
```

This is the code for the splashscreen

```
class Startscreen : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var auth: FirebaseAuth

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_startscreen)

        auth = Firebase.auth

        val user = auth.currentUser

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
            window.setFlags(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN)
        }

        if (user != null){
            Handler().postDelayed({
                    val intent = Intent(this@Startscreen, MainActivity::class.java)
                    startActivity(intent)
                    finish()
            }, 2000)
        }else{
            Handler().postDelayed({
                val intent = Intent(this@Startscreen, SignUp::class.java)
                startActivity(intent)
                finish()
            },2000)
        }
    }
```

This is the crash happening in my sign up screen on starting

```
class SignUp : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var etEmail: String
    private lateinit var etPass: String
    private lateinit var etPass2: String
    private lateinit var btn: Button

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up)
        etEmail = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_email).text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
        etPass = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.pass).text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
        etPass2 = findViewById<EditText>(R.id.et_pass2).text.toString().trim { it <= ' ' }
        btn = findViewById(R.id.btn_create)

        btn.setOnClickListener {
            dialog()
            if (isValid(etEmail, etPass, etPass2)){
                signUp(etEmail, etPass)
            }
        }

    }

    private fun isValid(email: String, pass: String,pass2: String ): Boolean{
        return if (email.isEmpty() && pass.isEmpty()){
            Toast.makeText(this@SignUp, "Fill in the blanks", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            false
        }else if(pass != pass2){
            Toast.makeText(this@SignUp, "Passwords do not match", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            false
        }else{
            true
        }
    }
    private fun signUp(email: String, pass: String){
        var auth: FirebaseAuth = Firebase.auth
        auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).addOnCompleteListener {
            dismiss()
            if (it.isSuccessful){
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUp, "Success",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show()
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(this@SignUp, it.exception!!.message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
    private fun dialog(){
        val dialog = Dialog(this)
        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog)
        dialog.show()
    }
    private fun dismiss(){
        Dialog(this).dismiss()
    }
}
```

Comment: Nothing to do with Firebase. You're calling `findViewById()` in a field initializer. You can't do that.

Comment: But when I remove the firebase code the app starts properly

Comment: Add the activity code

Comment: The problem is in `SignUp`, not `Startscreen`.

Comment: Please tell me more cause I can't see the problem. I initially only added the firebase code in the sign up screen which made the app crash on opening the activity. The same happened when I added the code in the splashcreen

Comment: Somewhere in the `SignUp` class, you probably have something like `private var textView = findViewById<TextView>(…)` outside of any class function. You can't call `findViewById()` there like that, because those initializations happen way before the instance has been properly set up as an `Activity`. If you need specific suggestions, you'll want to post the `SignUp` class.

Comment: How about binding? Can one use like that?

Comment: Share your signup code here. Crash happening in your signup class only.

Comment: The posted stack trace did not come from that code. Make sure you're looking at current logs.

Comment: make sure that you add SignUp to AndroidManifest.xml.

Comment: Your crash is happening when the Activity is first constructed, *before* `onCreate` runs (`Unable to instantiate activity`). That means it's being caused during initialisation, which usually means one if its top-level fields is trying to access something it can't access at that point. The error involves a call to `findViewById` (second half of the stacktrace) which means one of your fields (or an `init` block) is calling that during construction, like Mike said - and you can't do that. The code you posted has no sign of that and looks fine (but won't work!) so it's hard for us to give you help

Comment: Thank you guys. It finally worked

Answer (score 0):

The auth variable is initialized as follows

```
auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()
```

And not how you are doing

```
auth = Firebase.auth
```